# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, support

[Is there a set of closely related keys in modern popular music?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/79481/is-there-a-set-of-closely-related-keys-in-modern-popular-music) - This question has been closed as unclear what I was asking.  I could not know why.

Comment: Have you read all the comments asking for and giving information? If you edit your post to include responses to those that would help people understand what it is you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell, there are a couple of different ways your question could be interpreted:

- Is the term "closely related keys" meaningful in popular music?
- Is the concept of closely related keys useful in popular music?
- Does the term "closely related keys" have just one specific meaning in popular music?
- Does popular music have its *own* concept of "closely related keys", distinct from closely related keys in classical music?

In order for your question to be clear, you should at least make it clear which of these four things you're asking.

Also, your question has already been given an answer and you've marked the answer as accepted. If you're satisfied with the answer, is there any need to re-open the question?